# How to avoid NullPointerException for LOCATION_SERVICE?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, nullpointerexception

In my App, if my LOCATION_SERVICE is off i am getting the NullPointerException. But i want an alertDialog that will prompt the user of activating LOCATION_SERVICE. Can anyone please just tell me how to handle this exception?

```
 package com.bddevs.ddbllocator;
   import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (googleMap != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}
```

}

```
private void setUpMap() {
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

Location myLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

And here is the LOGCAT TRACE:

> 03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.bddevs.ddbllocator/com.bddevs.ddbllocator.DBBL_LOCATOR}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at com.bddevs.ddbllocator.DBBL_LOCATOR.setUpMap(DBBL_LOCATOR.java:73)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at com.bddevs.ddbllocator.DBBL_LOCATOR.setUpMapIfNeeded(DBBL_LOCATOR.java:38)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at com.bddevs.ddbllocator.DBBL_LOCATOR.onCreate(DBBL_LOCATOR.java:29)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
>   03-29 23:52:34.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11716):    ... 11 more

Comment: post the stack trace!!

Comment: Yea which line you're getting the exception

Comment: I have posted the trace. It is getting NullPointerException in myLocation.getLatitude(); this line when the LOCATION SREVICE is disabled. What do i do?

Answer (score 1):

If location service is disabled . getLastKnownLocation() will return null.

Add a null check

```
     Location myLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    If(myLocation == null ){
         // show the alert dialog
    }
   else {
         // do your stuff with latitude and longitude
  }
```